# Calling if in loop

Tags: php

I have this code,

var.php

```
function user_title($age) {
    $UserTitle = array(
    0  => array('18','Teenager'),
    1  => array('45','Adult'),
    2  => array('65', 'Senior')
    );
    foreach ($UserTitle as $user_title) {
        if ($age <= $user_title[0]) return $user_title[1];
    }
    return 'Unclassified';
}
```

profiles.php

```
$DB = $core_db->Execute("SELECT TOP (10) ID, Name, Age, Location FROM Profiles 
ORDER BY Name");
$num=0; 

while(!$DB->EOF){
 if ($DB->fields[0] != 0) {  
     echo'<div class="ID">'.$num.'</div>
         <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[1].'</div>
         <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[2].'</div>
         <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[3].'</div>
         **<div class="name">'.user_title($DB->fields[2]).'</div>**
        ';
     $num++;
    }
$DB->MoveNext();
```

The code is working fine but the value `.user_title($DB->fields[2]).'` is repeating in all titles column as the value from the profile owner of first row.
ex
1 Adam 30 **Adult** (correct)
2 Suzei 10 **Adult** (incorrect)
3 Dima 70 **Adult**
4 Hanna 30 **Adult**

Comment: use function you mean?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, Any idea?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, how to make a function in new .php file to use this if conditions in my other loops? instead of adding if elseif elseif all the time just to use the function or something.

Comment: You could make a function in a file with your IFs logic and include that file in profiles.php and the new php. Now how to make a function is already in php documentation. You can refer that.

Comment: @KeralPatel any example, it didn't work with me.

Comment: "The code is working fine but [...] is repeating" No, it is not. Your code, as shown in your post, indeed works fine. It does not generate wrong labels as you claim at all, which we can trivially verify: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d48ae5c8f5d611a531334d7b3ab88ff2244f495 so start inspecting your DB records: what's _actually_ in `$DB->fields[2]`? And don't guess: print it, and its type, etc. Find out what's _really_ in that field.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the values in `$UserTitle` to integers e.g. `array(18,'Teenager')` and the comparison to `if ((int)$age <= $user_title[0])`?

Comment: @Nick no the same result, the $num was doing the same untill I  made it increasing $num++; before $DB->MoveNext();  and that made instead of having num 1 in all have 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: I don't see how the value can be echo'ed correctly in this line `<div class="name">'.$DB->fields[2].'</div>` but not be correct in this line `<div class="name">'.user_title($DB->fields[2]).'</div>`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help and effort.
I removed "0  => " from the array and it worked.